# GCP - Connect to VM Instance from Separate Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ip-address, firewall, service-discovery

I have a kubernetes cluster that comprises my application and a database that I host on a separate VM instance (outside of the cluster). The database should be listening on port 27017 (I confirm this using netstat). I want to be able for my services in my cluster to connect to this database. I recieve errors about the connection timing out. This leads me to believe that a) the service discovery in my cluster is not working correctly (most likely a configuration issue) or b) there is some firewall that is blocking my requests.

To allow my external database to be discovered, I have defined a service and a custom endpoint for my database. Here is the service definition:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: db-service
 namespace: production
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Here is the endpoint definition:

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: db-service
 namespace: production
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: <internal-ip>
   ports:
     - port: 27017
```

I have tried using both the external and internal ips for the endpoint definition (using the internal ip makes the most sense to me).

The only network tags I have on my VM instance hosting my database is 'http-server' and 'https-server' (default tags allowing for http/https traffic).

What in my approach is preventing requests from nodes in my cluster from being received by my db being hosted on the VM instance?

Comment: Where is that Separate Cluster located? Which service type you use? Can you check your firewall settings?

Comment: Why your endpoint definition use the port 27017? I expected the port 5000 isn't it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Just a typo. It should be 27017, not 5000.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I have the "default-allow-internal" firewall option applying to all. What other firewall settings should I look for? Not sure what you mean by service type. As for location, they are both hosted within the same GCP Project, but one is in zone us-central1-a and another is in us-central1-b...do they need to be in the same zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my database was not listening for remote connections (for postgresql, check out pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf).